# Why need to return a function in Reagent component?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

From the [Reagent introduction](https://reagent-project.github.io/), a simple timer component:

```clojure
(defn timer-component []
  (let [seconds-elapsed (r/atom 0)]
    (fn []
      (js/setTimeout #(swap! seconds-elapsed inc) 1000)
      [:div
       "Seconds Elapsed: " @seconds-elapsed])))
```

and below it reads

> The previous example also uses another feature of Reagent: a component
> function can return another function, that is used to do the actual
> rendering. This function is called with the same arguments as the
> first one.
>
> This allows you to perform some setup of newly created components
> without resorting to React’s lifecycle events.

Can someone remind me of the underlying principle here? Why do we need this anonymous function? Why not just

```clojure
(defn timer-component []
  (let [seconds-elapsed (r/atom 0)]
    (js/setTimeout #(swap! seconds-elapsed inc) 1000)
    [:div
     "Seconds Elapsed: " @seconds-elapsed])))
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I remember, Reagent calls `timer-component` every time it wants to render - potentially setting up the same piece of state (`seconds-elapsed`) over and over again.

By returning that anonymous function instead, it tells Reagent "use this to render `timer-component`". This way your state setup is separated from rendering, and like your doco quote says, its a way to perform state setup without using Reacts lifecycle events.

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;dr**: The anonymous function that is returned is the `render` method, which every component must have. You can elide the anonymous function if you use the [`with-let` macro](https://dev.to/icncsx/reagent-101-pt-2-three-forms-5c0o) in Reagent.

The indispensable part of a React component is a [`render` function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#lifecycle-methods), which takes a single object argument and returns a React element. The difference between `render`
and the component constructor is that, while both methods are called upon construction, `render` [is called on each update](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/). (For instance, if someone calls the `setState` method of the component).

In the above example, the difference between the inner, anonymous function and the outer `timer-component` function is the same as between `render` and the constructor. Notice that the anonymous function [closes over](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20closure,between%20uses%20of%20the%20closure.) the variables bound in the `let` clause, which allows it to be stateful. If `timer-component` itself were the `render` function, then it would be called on every update, and `seconds-elapsed` would be endlessly reset to zero.

See the doc on the Reagent repo called "[Creating Reagent Components](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md)".